# Migrate InnoDB tables to PBXT

Tags: mysql, innodb, pbxt

Is there any migration procedures or tools to migrate a Database (Liferay database to be exact) from InnoDB to PBXT?

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with just doing an ALTER TABLE? you might have to remove the foreign keys, change all of the tables, and add foreign keys back.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name ENGINE=PBXT;
```

for each of your tables. If you have lots of tables, take a look at [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) as a possible automation solution. With it, you'd do something like:

```
mk-find <db_name> --engine InnoDB --exec "ALTER TABLE %D.%N ENGINE=PBXT" --print
```